# Any way to dynamically access lots of properties, modifying the name

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

Is there any way to dynamically access a property name, changing which property is called based on a string? Situation is this, I have the user selecting from a list of things on one screen and depending on what they pick, I need to modify the UI on the next. Thing is I have several things to set for each item they pick. The two screens are linked in that each property on the two screens have the same start to the property name i.e. "itemOne", "itemTwo", etc. so I have prepareForSegue set an array on the second screen of the numerical tags the user picked (and I've converted those to words), but Im wondering if i can, depending on if that number was selected can i call self.[dynamically generated].height.

I know I can set a property for each and just check each one on the second screen, but I was wondering if I couldn't do something with less code where I cycle thru and set each, just changing the property name that is actually set.

Comment: Search on "Key-Value Coding (KVC)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As maddy hinted, take a look at the method `setValue:forKey:`. That will let you set a value in an object using a string key name.

The method `setValue:forKeyPath:` will even let you traverse an object hierarchy, like `@"someObject.aDictionary.someKey.subProperty"`.

KVC is slower than direct property access, and can't be verified at compile time. You code crashes at runtime if the target object doesn't respond to the key. (With a message like "The object xxx is not key-value compliant for the key zzz")

Comment: thanks! so using that i could do that using self as the receiver and then the key is the property name like itemOne? then work down the hierarchy to get to height?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "work down the hierarchy." Are you talking about using setValue:forKeyPath?

Comment: been looking at it and got it to work mostly, thank you so much. how do you get around the things that aren't compliant?

Comment: @skinsvan00afg, make sure the target object has a property, instance variable, or, in the case of dictionary, key/value pair, that matches the key you're using.

Comment: thanks! i got it! last question, any way to use this technique to call a method?

Comment: You mean you have a string method name and you want to call that method? Try NSSelectorFromString. You'd convert your string to a selector, then use performSelector:, performSelector:withObject:, or one of the other variants.

Comment: an Upvote to my extra answer comment would be appreciated. BTW (totally off-topic) are you in the Washington DC area? I assume your handle refers to the DC football team. (I am in northern Virginia.)

Comment: hey there, yea i was up voting when someone came to my desk, got distracted, sorry. and yes, I'm in DC! unfortunately a big skins fan:-(     i actually wanted to clarify, the method i want to call is the same, but i want to dynamically decide which properties call it. that possible?